# Tomcat - Unusual logs

Tags: java, spring-mvc, centos, tomcat7

I am seeing a few log entries which looks suspicious. Not a single request from listed below is actually for the application. Can someone advise me on what I should do? This is the first ever application I have deployed on server.

**Entries in catalina.out**

```
Mar 16, 2013 7:46:11 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm authenticate
WARNING: An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "admin"
```

**Entries in localhost_access_log**

```
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:04 +0530] "GET HTTP/1.1 HTTP/1.1" 400 -
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:04 +0530] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 969
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:05 +0530] "GET /admin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 981
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:06 +0530] "GET /admin/pma/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 989
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:06 +0530] "GET /admin/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1003
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:07 +0530] "GET /db/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 975
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:08 +0530] "GET /dbadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 985
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:08 +0530] "GET /myadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 985
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:10 +0530] "GET /mysql/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 981
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:12 +0530] "GET /mysqladmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 991
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:13 +0530] "GET /typo3/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1003
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:14 +0530] "GET /phpadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 987
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:15 +0530] "GET /phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 991
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:15 +0530] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 991
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:16 +0530] "GET /phpmyadmin1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 993
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:17 +0530] "GET /phpmyadmin2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 993
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:17 +0530] "GET /pma/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 977
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:18 +0530] "GET /web/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 999
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:19 +0530] "GET /xampp/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1003
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:19 +0530] "GET /web/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 977
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:20 +0530] "GET /php-my-admin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 995
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:20 +0530] "GET /websql/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 983
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:21 +0530] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 991
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:22 +0530] "GET /phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 991
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:22 +0530] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 995
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:23 +0530] "GET /php-my-admin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 995
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:23 +0530] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.2.3/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1003
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:24 +0530] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.2.6/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1003
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:24 +0530] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1003
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:25 +0530] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.4/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1003
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:26 +0530] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.5-rc1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1011
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:26 +0530] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.5-rc2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1011
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:27 +0530] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.5/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1003
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:27 +0530] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.5-pl1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1011
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:28 +0530] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.6-rc1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1011
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:28 +0530] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.6-rc2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1011
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:29 +0530] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.6/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1003
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:29 +0530] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.7/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1003
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:30 +0530] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.7-pl1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1011
210.44.159.49 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:24:31 +0530] "GET HTTP/1.1 " 400 -
69.175.54.106 - - [16/Mar/2013:00:44:54 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 7959
66.249.75.14 - - [16/Mar/2013:04:27:44 +0530] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 971
2.122.109.242 - - [16/Mar/2013:16:50:17 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7959
2.122.109.242 - - [16/Mar/2013:16:50:17 +0530] "GET /css/style_new.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2.122.109.242 - - [16/Mar/2013:16:50:17 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 973
2.122.109.242 - - [16/Mar/2013:16:50:26 +0530] "GET /OfferedOnRent.html HTTP/1.1" 200 17666
2.122.109.242 - - [16/Mar/2013:16:50:26 +0530] "GET /images/20130313094059_0_thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 4020
2.122.109.242 - - [16/Mar/2013:16:50:26 +0530] "GET /images/20130312105214_0_thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 2961
2.122.109.242 - - [16/Mar/2013:16:50:26 +0530] "GET /images/20130312051229_0_thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 3714
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:40:30 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:40:31 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:40:31 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:40:31 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:40:32 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:40:32 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:40:32 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:40:32 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:46:09 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:46:09 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:46:10 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:46:10 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:46:10 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:46:10 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:46:11 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:46:11 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens all the time and <s>is probably</s> **is absolutely** not even a physical human being. People write scripts to try and get a successful result from any version of PHPMyAdmin, try an SSH attempt on just about every account name and password possible, or just go for anything and everything that could have a potential vulnerability. When you have a server on a public, open IP address, these things are bound to happen.

When someone attempts to access a website, a `GET` request is executed on the HTTP server. This, so obviously a script (look at the timestamps), is trying to `GET` generic names, for every `GET` request, a log entry is created in Apache (or Tomcat Apache in your case) for said `GET` and it's outcome. The majority of these entries are [HTTP 404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) errors, which as most know mean that the resource was not found.

There are several resources to help server admins track or block such activity:

[fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org)

[DenyHosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/)

[LogWatch](http://www.logwatch.org)

The best recommendation is to one, patch often, especially if you see one listed as a security patch, and two, use a firewall, opening only the absolute most needed ports from your server to the open world.

Comment: Thanks Chris. As a first measure i have added two IP's in blocked list in Lxguard.

Answer (score 1):

Have you secured your installation?

Looks to me, that the manager app is accessible from outside.
180.166.74.227 - - [16/Mar/2013:19:46:09 +0530] "HEAD /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 -

You should take steps to secure the manager.
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Securing_tomcat#Securing_Manager_WebApp

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like someone is trying to hack your server.